# What is $\frac{dXX^T}{dX}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

Given $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, what is $$\dfrac{dXX^T}{dX}?$$ I'm aware it is a order 4 tensor.

Comment: I don't know what the standard definitions or notations are in this context, but if we were to think of $dX$ as an infinitely small change in $X$ and $dXX^T$ as the corresponding change in $XX^T$, then I would guess that the value of the derivative at any point would be a linear transformation from the space of $n\times r$ matrices to the same of $n\times n$ matrices.  If $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $B\in\mathbb R^{r\times n}$, then $A\,dX\,B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and every linear transformation from the first space to the second would be a _sum_ of finitely many things of that form.

Comment: Typo: "same of $n\times n$ matrices" ----> "space of $n\times n$ matrices". ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 5):

$(X+H)(X+H)^{T}=XX^{T}+\underbrace{XH^{T}+HX^{T}}_{\text{first order terms}}+HH^{T}$

Comment: To add, in [vectorized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) form this becomes $(I \otimes X)P + X \otimes I$, where $P$ is the vectorization transpose operator defined by $P \text{vec}(A) := \text{vec}(A^T)$, and $\otimes$ is the Kronecker product (matricized version of the tensor product).

Comment: So then you'd have $dXX^T = X\ dX^T + dX\  X^T$.  The actual value of the derivative would be the linear transformation from $\mathbb R^{n\times r}$ to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ that maps $A\in\mathbb R^{n\times r}$ to $XA^T+AX^T\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

A pair of 4th order tensors arise naturally from matrix-matrix derivatives
$$\eqalign{
\omega      &= \frac {\partial{{\mathbf{X^T}}}} {\partial{{\mathbf{X}}}},\,\,\,\omega_{ijkl} = \delta_{il} \delta_{jk} \cr
\varepsilon &= \frac {\partial{{\mathbf{X}}}} {\partial{{\mathbf{X}}}},\,\,\,\varepsilon_{ijkl} = \delta_{ik} \delta_{jl} \cr
} $$
Using these, you can write the derivative as
$$\eqalign{
{\mathbf{\frac {\partial(X\cdot X^T)} {\partial X} }} &= {\mathbf{X\cdot\omega + \varepsilon\cdot X^T}} \cr
} $$